# Hilbert Space structure on path space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $E:L^2([0,1],H)$ be the set of all continuous paths into $H$ which are continuous.  How can we make $E$ into a separable Hilbert-space?  I'm thinking the completion of the subset of $E$ for which the inner-product
$$
<f,g> \triangleq \int_0^1 \langle f_t,g_t\rangle_H dt,
$$
is finite, defines a complete inner product on the path space with respect to the above inner product, where $\langle x,y\rangle_H$ is the inner product on $H$.

But I'm uncertain if I made a mistake; have I overlooked something?

For example if $H=L^2(U;\mathbb{R})$, where $U$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then is:
$$
<f,g> \triangleq \int_0^1 \langle f_t,g_t\rangle_H dt
=
\int_0^1 
\int_U
f_t(u),g_t(u)
du
dt,
$$
,
$$

Comment: Your subset is the entire $E$. However, the natural completion will consist of $L^2$-maps into $H$, not of continuous maps.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant.  Thanks for pointing that out.